# I lost 5 kgs in first 3 months of gym but now i am stuck

Tags: exercise, squats, bodyweight

I am 21 years 5ft 6in and my weight is 80 kg.

I started going to the gym about 4 months back and lost 5 kgs, but now I am stuck. I seem to look slimmer but the scale doesn't move.

I am doing 20 min cardio (treadmill and stepper) then 10 min cycling and then ab routine and then half hour aerobics including squats, lunges, jumping.

I want to lose a lot of weight (at least 10 kg) and my target date is one year which will be completed in October.
My diet:

Breakfast

- Glass of water
- Any fruit
- 1 Brown slice
- 1 cup tea
- Egg(occasionally)

Lunch

- Half roti
- Curry or generally I avoid lunch as I have my breakfast late

Snack

- Tea
- Few nuts

Dinner

- Chicken
- Half roti(not regularly)

I drink warm water and go to gym 6 days, and I have a once a month cheat day.

Comment: You're weight just shows how much you're affected by gravity; it doesn't give any indication to how much water, fat, muscle, or other tissues are in your body at the time of weighing. If you look slimmer, then you are most likely doing something that is working. Your next step may be to simply calculate your TDEE and track your food more closely or add in weighted exercises to your routine.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, it seems that you are facing a weight loss plateau, where in while losing weight after some time your body weight remains at the same level.
This is common thing while losing weight.
Things you can do while facing plateau are:
1) Re-evaluate your calorie intake.
   As you lose weight, not only does it become harder to lose, but your metabolism decreases, so you need to reevaluate your calorie intake to ensure that you are eating less calories than you are burning.
2) Carry out intense workouts and monitor and control everything you eat.

Answer (score 1):

Do not worry, you are just doing great. In the beginning you lose weight very fast but with the training you still lose some fat but you also gain some muscle in the meantime. That is why you weight same but you get more muscle. You may have TANITA like tests (fat percentage determination) periodically to follow fat percentage lose. Keep the good work up.

Answer (score 1):

If you have stalled in your weight loss it's possible your calories are too high or you are you are weighing yourself too frequently, or at irregular times. DO NOT take daily scale weigh as an indicator of weight loss, weigh yourself weekly, at the same time of day and pay attention to transient water weight. For example, my scale weight can fluctuate WILDLY in a 24 hour period due to salt and carb intake. Also, if weight loss is your goal and you are not tracking calories you are selling yourself short. Track calories (you can even do it on a piece of paper), be honest and be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure to do medical checkups to rule out metabolic diseases, like e.g. thyroid problems. The amount of food you eat during the entire day is similar to what I eat during breakfast alone ( 5ft 6in is similar to my height, but I weigh just 55 kg), so there might well be a metabolic problem here that needs to be addressed.

Then, assuming there is no underlying medical problem, you should increase the intensity of aerobic exercise and keep that up for longer. You should build up your fitness so that you can maintain at least 200 Watts for 45 minutes or longer. You'll then burn more than 500 Kcal, and in addition the fitness you will have build up allowing you to exercise at this level, will have led to an increased basal metabolic rate.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your body have reached a plateau which is quite common.. 
You should increase the intensity of your workout regime and should try different workout activites which involves whole body movement or activity rather than isolations. You can also try compound exercises. Plus, strength training helps reduce much weight as compared to cardio exercises. You can try to implement by switching alternative days.

Comment: You should also break your meal from 3 to 6 times a day, keeping the nutrition balance same. It will help in increasing your metabolism which effectively leads to weight loss